# How do i convert my URL's like www.example.com/profile.php?id=xyz into www.example.com/xyz?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url

I have got different pages in my website(portal) which may take one or more parameters from the URL.

So the URL `www.example.com/xyz` has to be solved into or like `www.example.com/profile.php?id=xyz` and the value id should be able to get using GET method.

I'm working on PHP. Any answers would be highly appreciated. (I'm new to PHP and have only basic+ knowledge in it. Please explain briefly.)

Comment: [This is a great resource.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained) There's a lot there to read through, but while someone could give you something brief that does what you're trying to do, what you're asking about really can't be _explained_ briefly.

Answer (score 0):

To go from: `www.example.com/profile.php?id=xyz` into `www.example.com/xyz` you can use the following rule in your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /profile.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Just make sure you clear your cache before testing this.